# How to reference existing component in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs4

I have panel with border layout:

```
    var panel = new Ext.Panel({
         width:'100%',
         height:'100%',
         layout:'border',
         renderTo:'wrapper',
         defaults: {
             collapsible: true,
             split: true,
             bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
         },
         items: [{
             title: 'Header',
             region: 'north',
             height: 150,
             minSize: 75,
             maxSize: 250,
             cmargins: '5 0 0 0',
             html: Ext.get("header-div").getHTML() 
         }
......
```

and I have a tree

```
 var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        xtype: 'tree-xml',
        id:'treegrid',
        title: treeTitle,
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%',
        renderTo: Ext.get("tree"),
....
```

My question is:how can I refernce tree in my panel, which means I want to append the tree into 
'north' region of panel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How to reference components in Extjs:

var treeReference = Ext.ComponentQuery.query ('tree-xml [title=treeTitle])[0]; // basically you are saying get me the first component you find that is a tree-xml and that its title is treeTitle

Check out the docs in sencha.
Be careful to refer to element 0 of the array (query method returns an array even if there is only 1 element matching).

Use methods add and remove from panels and  containers to achieve desired functionality.

Best regards.